# EE Debug Toolbar Installation Crash

Tags: add-on

I hate to complain about a freebie add-on - EE Debug Toolbar from mitra62 - but unfortunately installing EE Debug Toolbar has just caused me major problems.

The good news is that my site is still up.

The bad news is that I can't login as a superadmin at all.

The story is:

My EE site uses the latest version of EE and of MSM.

I just downloaded version 1.0 (RC1) of EE Debug Toolbar from Devot-ee.com

I followed the instructions on GitHub (just before it's current DDOS attack) including turning on the EE debugging reporting. I uploaded all the files that came with the download in the usual sections.

I went to Extensions and activated EE Debug. There was a list of things to activate, I believe I started with the first one on the list because it seemed the most general. I'm sorry but this is all I can recall about this step.

I got this error message:

Fatal error: Class 'XMLWriter' not found in /var/www/html/system/expressionengine/third_party/ee_debug_toolbar/libraries/xml_writer.php on line 35

My superadmin access to the site stalled there.

I went back to GitHub to look for help.

GitHub is experiencing a DD0S attack and is down.

I tried to log onto my super admin account from another browser and got the error message.

I got impatient and deleted all the EE Debug addons from the system and themes folder.

Now I just get a white screen when I try to log on to my superadmin account.

How do I get back in as superadmin now?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Jeanne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there may be files missing from your upload. I would try reuploading the add-on to make sure all files were included. The error seems to be pointing to a missing file within  the add-on's package directory.

In the meantime to get you back into the control panel, you can go into your database, find the `exp_extensions` table, find the EE Debug Toolbar record and set the value of the `enabled` field to `n`. This will disable the extension and should prevent it from interrupting your access to the control panel.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the exp_extensions table solved the superadmin login  problem.

Comment: The original problem occurred because EE Debug Toolbar has, <a href="https://github.com/accent-interactive/xml_writer">xml_writer.php</a> which is a class that extends XMLWriter which comes with PHP5 by default. Unfortunately, the configure command for PHP5 was written with "disable-xmlwriter" which is why the error message said "Class XMLWriter not found."

Comment: A followup: the site runs with Apache/2.2., Linux 5.5 (CentOS) and PHP/5.3.27 on a Rackspace cloud. By creating another .ini in the /etc/php.d/ directory, I was able to enable both XMLWriter and XMLReader.  For anyone who is just wading into these waters, as I am, the procedure is to: 1)create a file named XMLWriter.ini  2) put this code into the file: `extension=xmlwriter.so`  3) save and then restart Apache. Repeat for XMLReader, with appropriate file name changes.